# Why is firefox attempting to direct me to a Captive Portal, when I'm connected to my own router?

Tags: malware, web-browser, firefox, web, captive-portal

I am connected to my own router, and I know for a fact that I do not have a captive portal installed. Firefox displays a banner at the top of the page saying that "you must log in to this network before you can access the Internet.", with a button that says "Open Network Login Page" to its right.
The link forwards to http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt. Notably only one machine is affected. Just sort of wondering what the possible reasons are for getting suddenly seeing this.

I also know that someone hasn't set up a fake router SSID- because I can see that I'm connected to the router via the router's web-config utility

Comment: Not sure... maybe your router has a special configuration or a captive portal? Did you tried on other browser? from other pc or mobile device? is the same behavior?

Comment: Maybe your router is altering the success.txt page in some way, so Firefox doesn't recognise the clean response - so assumes a captive portal?

Comment: I see the banner in the corporate network I am working in because of a proxy that meddles with HTTP traffic. [From Firefox 54 onwards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1354245) you can disable the captive portal check by setting `network.captive-portal-service.enabled` to `false` in `about:config`.

Answer (score 6):

The captive portal detection works by requesting http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt (or something similar) and seeing if the expected contents are returned. Possibly something on your router, or computer is altering the page, so Firefox is assuming that there is a captive portal in the way?

Comment: To All: It's been 3+ years, but I thought I'd chime in. I am pretty sure it would be fine if it WERE http://..., but for the last few months, since v78 ~ 79, it opens https ://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt, but BECAUSE of the https, redirect is prevented and I get "success" instead of the login page.  I have to manually navigate to an http site to get the ToS page so that "You must log in..." will go away.
 I'm looking for an answer.  I'll try turning off the captive portal & see if that's viable.

Comment: @Chaos7703 Not sure if that was the issue three years ago, but it was the issue for me today, thanks. I fixed it by changing the address in captivedetect.canonicalURL to the https address in my about:config.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> I fixed it by changing the address in captivedetect.canonicalURL to
> the https address in my about:config. – mmaluff

This worked for me, too, it seems that a recent update broke the http address but the https version is working fine. This is preferable to disabling the detection entirely in case you do use a public network at some point and forget to turn it back on.